# Proving that a set is not $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Proving the a set *is* $G_\delta$ can often be done by construction. Proving the converse requires a much deeper argument. I'm new to this area of topology, and I'm asked, given a set, whether it is $G_\delta$ or not. I can't come up with any construction which would make it a $G_\delta$ set, but I have no idea how to approach the proof that it isn't. Are there generic methods of doing so?

Comment: Baire's theorem can come in handy, and it is sometimes the usual approach. But I would say it probably depends on the set in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Pedro Tamaroff's comment: in a complete metric space, the intersection of any two  dense $G_\delta$ sets is nonempty, by the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).  So a viable strategy is:

1. You have a set $A$ in a complete metric space $X$, and you suspect $A$ is not $G_\delta$.
2. Try to construct a "large" $G_\delta$ set $B$ that is disjoint from $A$.
3. If you manage the above so that $\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{B}$, then $A$ is not $G_\delta$.

Explanation: $\overline{A}$ is a complete metric space of its own. If $A$ was $G_\delta$, then $A$ and $B$ would be two dense $G_\delta$ sets in $\overline{A}$; yet their intersection is empty, contradicting  Baire's theorem.

Steps 2-3 are equivalent to constructing a "small" $F_\sigma$ set $C$ containing $A$, so that $\overline{A}\subseteq \overline{X\setminus C}$. Think of a way to efficiently cover $A$ with countably many closed sets.

Standard example: $A=\mathbb Q$, a subset of $\mathbb R$. Since $A$ is a countable union of singletons, we can have $C=A$, and since $\overline{A} = \overline{\mathbb R\setminus C} $, $A$ is not $G_\delta$.

Comment: This is great, thanks very much! Is there a good you would recommend on the topic?

Comment: @Phonon $G_\delta$ sets are not really a topic that you study on its own; it's a part of general (point-set) topology. See [Topology book recommendations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).